# Flex 3: How to Make Rights Symbol in a RadioButton Label

Tags: apache-flex, radio-button

I've got a Flex 3 site. I need to put the rights symbol, ®, in the radioButton's labels:

```
<mx:RadioButtonGroup id="myButtonGroup" itemClick="goClickHandler(event);"/>
    <mx:RadioButton  groupName="myButtonGroup" label="{answerA}" value="{answerA}"/>
    <mx:RadioButton  groupName="myButtonGroup" label="{answerB}" value="{answerB}"/>
```

I've got the label and value bound to:

[Bindable]
public var answerA:String;

[Bindable]
public var answerB:String;

I pull answerA and answerB from a database.

I guess that I need to use htmlText somehow. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: That's not a "rights" symbol, it's the registered trademark symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your font is supporting the "trademark simbol" then you don't need any html text.
Just save it like "My site ®" and it should work :)

Comment: Thank you, TiMeister. That was easy!